# How to pass the result of a function to another function in Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootbox

I created a function where users can enter a filename through Bootbox prompt input then I am calling this function in my datatable to set the name of the exported file with the value of the user's input.

My problem is : when i click on 'Save current Page' button the file is exported before then the prompt pops up. It should work the opposite way. First the prompt appears, the user enter the filename then the file is exported with this name.

Here is my code. I am passing `result` value from `myFunction()` to `filename` in datatable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var t = $('#example').DataTable({
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'excelHtml5',
      title: '',
      text: 'Save current page',
      filename: function() {
        return myFunction();
      },
      exportOptions: {
        modifier: {
          page: 'current'
        }
      },
      customize: function(xlsx) {
        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
        $('row c', sheet).attr('s', '0');
        $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '2');
      }
    }]

  });

  t.buttons().container()
    .appendTo('#example_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)');

  function myFunction() {
    bootbox.prompt("Enter the filename",
      function(result) {
        return result;
      });
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I replace the Bootbox input box with a sample javascript prompt then it's working fine and my file is exported with entered file name.

```
   function myFunction() {
    var filename = prompt("Please enter file name:");
    return filename; }
```

Any suggestion please how to pass the value of the user's input from my function to my datatable ? Thank you.

Comment: That's because prompt is syncronous, bootbox is assyncronous. You should do the exporting using a callback on bootbox

Comment: @Phiter  I added callback: function (result) { return result; } in my function but still not working. Can you guide me please how to adjust it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add everything into myFunction() then call the function 'onLoad':

```
function myFunction() {
    bootbox.prompt("Enter the filename", 
    function(result) {return  result;} );

    var t = $('#example').DataTable({
        buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            title: '',
            text: 'Save current page',
            filename: function () { return myFunction();},
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {page: 'current'} },
            customize: function(xlsx) {
                var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                $('row c', sheet).attr('s', '0');
                $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '2');
            }
        }
        ]

    } );

    t.buttons().container()
    .appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)' );
}
```

I've never messed with this specific tool, but I'd guess bootbox is probably not 'synchronized'